# Jackson Deserialize and Serialize with different field name

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, deserialization

I have a class that I want to deserialize and serialize with Jackson. Currently this is what I have

```
class Person {
    @JsonAlias("fullName")
    @JsonDeserialize(using = NameDeserializer.class)
    String name;
}
```

I want to be able to read from `{"fullName": "John Doe"}` and write to `{"name": "John Doe"}`.

I am also using Lombok to create setter and getter, so I could not use @JsonProperty on method level. Any idea how would I approach this, because currently it seems like the @JsonAlias is not working as expected. I'm using Jackson 2.10 to map object.

EDIT

Turns out using Alias works just fine. Though in figuring out how it didn't work the first time, I override lombok setter

```
@JsonProperty("firstName")
public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
}
```

From here I found out that my Deserializer is actually the problem.

Comment: You can write setter getter explicitly(don't worry there is not problem with lombok) and use @JsonProperty on them

Comment: Is there any other solution aside from overriding the setter?

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the custom deserializer, and annotate the field with `@JsonProperty`, which should make your scenario work:

```
class Person {
    @JsonAlias("fullName")
    @JsonProperty
    String name;
}
```

The custom deserializer controls how the deserialization is done, and this is where the alias is probably being ignored.

Comment: According the [docs](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.10/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAlias.html), `JsonAlias` "has no effect during serialization where primary name is always used", so yes it serializes to `name` but can deserialize from `fullName`.

Comment: I actually need then custom deserializer, because there are some modification that I need.

Comment: Then you can account for the alias in the deserializer code. Isn't that feasible? Then you'd remove the `JsonAlias`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use JsonProperty annotation with properties as it is written here https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations

```
public class Name {
    @JsonProperty("firstName")
    public String _first_name;
}
```

Comment: I want to serialize it as name, thus I cannot use JsonProperty